# Grayscale PHP, different type of gray

Tags: php, gd

```
$rgb = imagecolorat($im_org, $i, $j);  

$rr = ($rgb >> 16) & 0xFF;
$gg = ($rgb >> 8) & 0xFF;
$bb = $rgb & 0xFF;

$g = round(($rr + $gg + $bb) / 3);

$val = imagecolorallocate($im_org, $g, $g, $g);

imagesetpixel ($im_org, $i, $j, $val);
```

This is how I grayscale a picture, simply by setting each pixel. However, I would like to adjust how the grayscale outputs, like say I would want to add some more contrast and stuff. How would I do that?

Comment: You could try grayscale according to luminosity (looks more like the original while still being gray) instead of RGB-space.

Answer (score 0):

What about `imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);` ?